# Can I rebuild the Dalvik VM for my Android device?

Tags: android, dalvik

I am wishing to rebuild the Dalvik VM on my android device for my application analysis work. Specifically, I want when I run an apk file on my android device if it makes an HTTP connection to a certain address, it will automatically print the logcat.

Also, if that is possible then how do I change the Dalvik VM on an android device using the Dalvik VM that I rebuilt.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the Dalvik VM instead of a more suitable place in the Android SDK, like the networking stack? The DalvikVM doesn't know anything about what it's doing, it just runs bytecode.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your suggestions. However I have a question that when I rebuild the sdk it will help me to build an application from the source code rather than changing the way the application executes on Android device.

Comment: when i said "Android SDK" i meant the whole android stack. The whole android sitting on top of zygote, sitting on top of the linux kernel. the android studio facing part of the "android sdk" will most likely remain the same.

Comment: you need to flash the device with your own image (rom / nand) to change how apps run on your device. you can't get your changes to run on vanilla android (but perhaps a fake VPN could get the same effect you're looking for)

Comment: As far as I know, sdk will build the source code into dex files for Dalvik or ART to execute it. So I think that to change the application's behavior while the application is executing, there is only one way to change the VM running the application (ART or Dalvik). If there is a simpler or more feasible way, can you tell me clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a partial answer to some your question(s)...

First of all, your device most likely uses ART now, but if it is running DalvikVM, you will need to build an image (ROM or NAND) and then burn that to the device.

However, different devices come from different vendors, different vendors changed the Android SDK in different ways - as they felt like or needed to - and maybe even the Dalvik VM too - meaning you can't get their code. But you can get their images.

Modifying the Dalvik VM in that image is a severe reverse-engineering task however, so be ready to settle for running AOSP Android on your device (where you can actually change the Dalvik VM code if you need to, or the networking stack itself), if it even boots up or works properly on the said device (because vendors use different drivers and/or hacks for the hardware they're shipping)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am thinking that I will have to find another solution to my topic.